# Find subset of elements in an array that when summed equal any other element in the array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'd like to write an algorithm in Javascript for the following problem.

Given the following array [1,2,3,4,6], provide the number of subsets that equal any other element in the array.

For instance:

```
1+2 = 3
1+3 = 4
2+4 = 6
1+2+3 = 6
```

Answer: 4 subsets

I can calculate the sum of *pairs* of numbers that equal any other element in the array; however, I cannot find the sum of 2 or more elements (1+2+3) that equal any other element in the array.

How would I write an algorithm for this?  Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Good Link @JosephSilber

Comment: You can use dynamic programming. This is very classical subset sum problem. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

Comment: You first need to observe the problem in order to be able to arrive at a solution.

What you have is: a sorted array of unique values. So you first need to think how to get from [6,4,1,4,3,2,3,6,2] to [1,2,3,4,6].

Then, you notice you're starting from the first element in the array and then move up with addition (notice I changed how your test case is written to highlight this):
1+2 = 3; 
1+3 = 4; 
1+2+3 = 6; 
2+4 = 6

Comment: The rest of the cases are tested in the algo but are also being dismissed: 1+4; 1+2+3+4; 2+3; 2+3+4. What I, and the rest, are trying to say, is that this is not a JS problem yet, and any programming language solution needs an algorithmic base to start from.

Comment: @JosephSilber: I was merely asking a question.  Certainly not cause for being accused of intellectual dishonesty.  In the future, I'll be sure to post my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple solution that should be easy to grasp. Note that this is not a very fast algorithm, but for shorter arrays it works well.

The idea is to generate a bit mask for every combination, and then for each mask add the numbers in the array indicated by a 1 in the bit mask string:

```
console.log("Number of subsets: " + getNumberOfSubsets([1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 2));

function getNumberOfSubsets(numbers, minimumNumbersInSubset) {
    var numberOfBits = Math.pow(2, numbers.length);
    var numOfSubsets = 0;

    for (var i=0;i<numberOfBits;i++) {
        var bitField = i.toString(2);
        while(bitField.length < numbers.length) {
            bitField = "0" + bitField;
        }

        var sum = 0;
        var addedNumbers = [];
        for (j=0;j<bitField.length;j++) {
            if (bitField.charAt(j) == "1") {
                sum += numbers[j];
                addedNumbers.push(numbers[j]);
            }
        }

        if (addedNumbers.length >= minimumNumbersInSubset && numbers.indexOf(sum) !== -1) {
            numOfSubsets += 1;
            console.log("Iteration " + i + ": " +
                        bitField+", " + (addedNumbers.join("+") + "=" + sum));
        }
    }

    return numOfSubsets;
}
```

Outputs the following in the console to show the successful combinations:

```
Iteration 10: 01010, 2+4=6
Iteration 20: 10100, 1+3=4
Iteration 24: 11000, 1+2=3
Iteration 28: 11100, 1+2+3=6
Number of subsets: 4
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9HhSs/